# Swift: Segue into a UITableView Search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to segue **into** a UITableView Search. I already have the uitableview and search bar implemented and working. Now I want to add a button, that when clicked, opens up the search view with the keyboard out. How can I implement this?

**Challenge:** How can I put this button on separate view controller?

I have looked up ways to segue into a search bar, but all I have found are ways to segue out of a search.

My Code:

```
/*Search*/
var searched: Bool = false
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarReal: UISearchBar!
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getSortedSectionList()
    tableView.reloadData()
    if searched {
        searchBarReal.becomeFirstResponder()
        searched = false
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    setUpIcons()
    searchBarReal.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Are you adding UISaerchBarDelegate to your view controller class? Can you add your prepareForSegue method from your other controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell your searchBar to becomeFirstResponder.

code example:

**Initial View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func bttnTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if segue.identifier == "next" {

        let nextVc = segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController
        nextVc.shouldSearchBarRespond = true
    }
}

}
```

**Next View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class NextViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var shouldSearchBarRespond: Bool?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if shouldSearchBarRespond == true {

        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Will this work even if the search bar is in a different view controller?

Comment: Sure can, you'll need to add a property to your controller with the search bar and then update it in your prepareForSegue method, then in your viewDidAppear you can check the property and if it matches you can set the searchBar to becomeFirstResponder

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a try

Comment: I've been trying this out and debugging for a while. I created an IBOutlet for my search bar, but my first view controller thinks it is nil when I call it in my prepareForSegue method. Here is my method:
`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
            //open up the search
            if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? DayViewViewController {
                //vc.searchBarReal.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: You should create a new property on DayViewViewController, a bool, that you can set in prepareForSegue, then you can check in DayViewViewController if the bool is true, if it is, then use the outlet for the search bar to tell it to be the first responder

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I'm running it now

Comment: Okay Its changing view controllers, but the search bar is not becoming the first responder

Comment: I put the boolean check in ViewWillAppear

Comment: Is DayViewViewController a UISearchBarDelegate and if so did you assign the delegate property of your search bar to self?

Comment: I don't assign the delegate in code but I do in the Storyboard

Comment: You still need to make the view controller a UISearchBarDelegate and then use the outlet variable to assign the search bar's delegate property to self, I've added a code example to my answer

Comment: Done, it still doesn't load the bar as a first responder

Comment: Alright I fixed it. Your code works only if `searchBarReal.becomeFirstResponder()` is called in `viewDidLoad` and not `viewWillLoad`